# Binding in ItemTemplate on KeyValuePair not working

Tags: c#, binding, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I've got a problem get binding working in an ItemTemplate of a ListView. My binding target is a KeyValuePair. Following Code:

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewDataItems" CanDragItems="True" DragItemsStarting="event" SelectionMode="Multiple">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
        <TextBlock Text=":"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Parameter != null) {
    IDataSourceExtension extension = (IDataSourceExtension)e.Parameter;
    pageTitle.Text = extension.Name;
    // Type of LastData: List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>
    listViewDataItems.ItemsSource = extension.LastData;                
  }
}
```

The ItemsSource is set fine and contains KeyValuePairs, but displaying the key and value in the ListView is not working. I work under .Net4.5 Beta in an metro style app.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> LvItems { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.DataContext = this;
   LvItems = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
   LvItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Idx", 5));
   LvItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Ido", 12));
}
```

And used your itemtemplate, and it worked like a charm.

So my best guess is that:

1) You need to use an ObservableCollection to be notified of changes in the collection (otherwise the items may be here but the ListView won't refresh because it is not aware the collection has changed).

2) You should refrain from directly setting a collection: make it readonly and add items one by one instead of setting the collection. (or raise PropertyChanged in the setter of the collection).

EDIT: complete code.

```
<Window x:Class="ConverterCombinerTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConverterCombinerTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LvItems}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=":"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            LvItems = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
            LvItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Idx", 5));
            LvItems.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Ido", 12));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>> LvItems { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(String _Prop)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_Prop));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried both, but it didn't make it work. The Setter of the List already called PropertyChanged(), ObservableCollection doesn't help. Setting the items one by one dosn't help too. I modified my code and edited your collection LvItems instead of LastData, it's also not displayed.

Comment: Do you set the DataContext properly? the example i posted along with your exact XAML works on my computer.

Comment: I think so, I added to my xaml ListView code `ItemsSoruce={Binding}` and set in c# `listViewData.DataContext = extension.LastData;`. still the right number of items is shown but only ': ' not 'key: value'. Did you tested it with .net4.5 beta?

Comment: Set the DataContext of the entire Windows/UserControl, not of each particular element. I add my entire code.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ I created a new clean metro style project, added your code, added my template, doesn't work. Have you tried it in an metro style app?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I'm really surprised as this is a simple scenario. You copy pasted just my code in a MainWindow and its code-behind?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Maybe it's a bug in metro/.net beta. I'll try to get an answer in the developer forums for win 8.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with RTM tooling. Did either of you find an answer?